# Can I compile and run a MVC1.0 application under .NET 4.0?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-4.0

We have an MVC1.0 application that is compiled against  and runs with .Net Framework 3.5.

The application was scanned for security and the scanning organisation reported

> Microsoft ASP.NET ValidateRequest Filters Bypass Cross-Site Scripting
>   Vulnerability

https://community.qualys.com/docs/DOC-3495

> What versions of Microsoft ASP.NET are vulnerable? Microsoft has
>   confirmed that ASP.NET versions 1 and 2 are both vulnerable.
>   Additionally, Qualys has confirmed that ASP.NET version 3 is also
>   vulnerable, as it includes the vulnerable component from version 2 by
>   default. We have tested this in our Labs and confirmed the exploit
>   works on a fully patched version 3.

We are already upgrading our application to MVC3, but that takes some more time to finish.

Is there any chance I can run and compile a MVC1.0 application against .NET 4.0?

Answer (score 1):

This may arise compatibility issues, Even though there are very few dependencies over the .net framework. 
You can refer the following posts.

[Is ASP.NET MVC 1 forwards compatible with ASP.NET MVC 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202455/is-asp-net-mvc-1-forwards-compatible-with-asp-net-mvc-2)
[ASP.Net MVC 1.0 in Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232368/asp-net-mvc-1-0-in-visual-studio-2010)

Comment: This is good information - but not related to the original question which has to do with the framework version itself.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, anything that runs on .NET 3.5 should function and complile just fine in .NET 4.0, with perhaps some warnings about depreciated functions, but they will still work.

In case you are still curious/not comfortable, there are some tools available to help verify dependencies and other items such at [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Best recommendation... try it! I can't think of any other reason than what Tommy mentioned about deprecated functions. Also, you can update most of your references with

```
Update-Package
```

without arguments.

If it compiles fine, do a quick test run over the views. If nothing seems broken, then it probably isn't.